# Ignoring lines from grep matching any element in a bash array

Tags: bash, grep

I have an array (superStringIgnoreArray) containing superstrings like "formula", "forest", "foreign", "fortify", and I am running the following grep lines:

```
eval 'find "$SEARCH_DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -HniI "$hitWord" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"'
eval 'find "$SEARCH_DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -HniI --color=always "$hitWord" | more'
```

Where hitWord in this instance would be "for".

How can I return all hits that do not match any entry in my superStringIgnoreArray? (so lines containing "for", "form", "fort" "fork" "forming" would be returned, but "fortify", "forest", etc would not).

Example output:

```
srcToSearch/open_source_licenses.txt:12:source software packages. One or more such open_source_licenses.txt files may there**for**e
srcToSearch/open_source_licenses.txt:19:-- **For** vCenter Server 5.5u2 GA, the license in**for**mation listed in Parts 2,
srcToSearch/open_source_licenses.txt:22:-- **For** vCenter Server on Linux Virtual Appliance 5.5u2 GA, the license
srcToSearch/open_source_licenses.txt:23:in**for**mation listed in Parts 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 are applicable.
srcToSearch/open_source_licenses.txt:29:document.  This list is provided **for** your convenience; please read further if
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: Be more specific with your question - are you looking for files, that contain `$hitWord`, except those, that are on your ignored list, which is defined as bash array?

Comment: No, I am recursively looking through a directory "SEARCH_DIR" for files containing the $hitWord, and outputting the lines within those files which contain $hitWord to console and too an output file. I simply want to omit all hits against any word in my superStringIgnoreArray.

Comment: Providing an actual value for `superStringIgnoreArray` would be a place to start. A lot of the time people in the bash tag call something an "array" when it's actually a string with spaces or newlines; including the output of `declare -p superStringIgnoreArray` in the question would settle that ambiguity.

Comment: (and... no, seriously, why *are* you using `eval`? See [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for some discussion on why its use is strongly discouraged).

Comment: ...btw, do you need to worried about words from `superStringIgnoreArray` being present in filenames? This is considerably easier if you don't.

Comment: As far as the use of eval is concerned, it is probably leftover from some legacy code and I did not know enough/catch it.

Comment: Good question Charles Duffy regarding the filenames. Short answer not *really* but it would be nice if the filenames where left alone.

Comment: if you can create some simplified input files with all edge cases covered and expected output it will help.

Answer (score 3):

**`grep`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
superStringIgnoreArray=("formula" "forest" "foreign" "fortify")
grep -HniIr "$hitWord" "$SEARCH_DIR"/* \
| grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${superStringIgnoreArray[@]}") | tee "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

Comment: I'm curious as to whether the logic in a now-deleted answer by @karakfa intended to filter out the ignored words only from the contents, and not from the filenames, actually reflects the OP's intent. This is definitely the easier thing (though I might use `<(printf '%s\n' "${superStringIgnoreArray[@]}")` instead of mucking with `IFS` and using `echo`).

Comment: `<()` already runs in a subshell, so you don't need to start another one with `$()` -- `<(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${array[@]}")`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, `<(printf '%s\n' "${superStringIgnoreArray[@]}")` is realy nicer, good catch

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes that was the intent until I saw the delimiter in the contents as well, so posted a workaround now.

Comment: Great feedback everyone, I appreciate your time and help on this. Sorry I have not been able to implement any of the suggestions since I have been in about 2-3 hours of meetings this morning, but I hope to get after it this afternoon and respond.

Comment: I get "no such file or directory" for the second grep line. grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${superStringIgnoreArray[@]}") | tee "$OUTPUT_FILE"

Comment: The above solution didn't seem to filter entries from my ignoreArray

Comment: @user1524459, you did not even post your *ignoreArray* definition. The above approach works for the currently presented array

Comment: okay, I didn't mean the problem was specific to my ignoreArrayEntries, just that the filtering behavior wasn't expected. In my test case, I added "nevertheless" to my ignore array, and was able to verify it was an superStringIgnoreArray element, and I had the following line spat out to output:

srcToSearch/open_source_licenses.txt:53908:(11) If your Modified Version has been derived from a Modified Version made by someone other than you, you are ***nevertheless*** required to ensure that your Modified Version complies with the requirements of this license.

Comment: If you create a text file in $SEARCH_DIR with a bunch of words in it, and add the words from the superStringIgnoreArray mentioned above to your text file, and populate $hitWord with "for" it still returns the superStringIgnoreArray words in grep

Comment: The problem I had was caused by me appending --color=always to my grep line.

Answer (score 1):

since you're outputting the filenames, chaining another grep won't be trivial, but you can achieve the same with `awk`

```
$ grep -HniIFr "$hitWord" "$SEARCH_DIR" | 
  awk 'BEGIN   {OFS=FS=":"}
       NR==FNR {a[tolower($0)]; next} 
               {f=$1;n=$2;$1=$2="";
                for(k in a) if(tolower($0)~k) next}
               {$1=f;$2=n;print}' blacklist -
```

here `awk` limits the matches after the filename with `:` delimiter.  If you "hitWord" is a literal adding `-F` will help. `awk` is still doing pattern matching though.  `tolower()` is to make the second step case insensitive too.

Since delimiter ":" can appear within the body, we can't depend on $3 in `awk`, instead, store $1 and $2; remove them from the line, match and add them back before printing.  I guess at this point you can add the first grep functionality to this awk as well.

However, I think without `-o` flag, this and other line based solutions will fail when there is a actual match and unwanted match on the same line.  If the unwanted superstrings are few, perhaps a negative lookback/lookahead pattern is a better solution.

If your `blacklist` is not a file but an array, you can do file substitution as in the other answer, replace with

```
... | awk '...' <(printf '%s\n' "${superStringIgnoreArray[@]}") -
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the syntax/pseudocode "blacklist -" at the end?

Comment: "blacklist" is the file name that lists the unwanted words,i.e. that's where the your "superstrings" are listed. `-` indicates the other file comes from the input stream (piped in).

Comment: They are stored in an array (created from much earlier in the script). My hitlist file is formatted weird so I have a parser I wrote to read that in, and a previous grep/count run (thanks for the help yesterday) to tally up potential candidates to omit.

Comment: OK, see the update for file substitution.  However, think about the case where you have a real hit and a superstring on the same line.  These approaches will eliminate that line and you'll miss a real hit.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that. This would occur if and only if there were 2 or more superstrings from the same hitword on the same line, and you chose to omit the line based on an ignore entry. One idea we had would be to run everything a second time, change the hitlist to be the ignore entries (which are very specific), and re-run the script. Another idea would be of course to somehow flag a line containing two or more superstrings/hitwords. So short answer, I am working on that.

Comment: This solution works as I requested though, however is there any way to include the file and line number to the line, and highlight the hit on the console output (like --color=always on the grep line)?

Comment: "filename:line" should be printed with the updated code.  For coloring: I'm not sure with `awk`, perhaps you can `grep` the final output with color option, now should only have the hit words.

Comment: Scratch that, this actually doesn't eliminated words from the superStringIgnoreArray for my output. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: if you can create some simplified input files with all edge cases covered and expected output it will help.

Comment: The problem I had was caused by me appending --color=always to my grep line.